# Place one WPF Window next to another

Tags: c#, wpf, window, location

I used this:

```
WindowStartupLocation = System.Windows.WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
```

to position the first window (W1) in the middle of the screen.

With a button click, I want to place a new window (W2) beside the first one.

[Image showing how it should be   (W=Window)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bN7Kj.png)

Comment: As a quick glance, it seems just matter of basic calculation plus minus. Try to get the values of location of firstWindow and width, height.(through firstWindow.Width and firstWindow.Height). And after simple calculation, set the calculated values into secondWindow.Left and secondWindow.Top something like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do the job :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window2 w2 = new Window2();
    w2.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.Manual;
    w2.Left = this.Left + this.Width;
    w2.Top = this.Top + (this.Height - w2.Height) / 2;
    w2.Show();
}
```

If you want the second window to track changes to the size and position of the first then you'd need to handle the appropriate events and correct the position of the second window using similar logic to the above.

Comment: You may want to use ActualWidth and ActualHeight to account for DPI adjustments and measurements.